# Jira REST API for configuring dashboard gadget

Tags: api, jira, dashboard

My goal is to create dashboard gadgets automatically and programatically.
I tried to create dashboard gadget, Filter Results, using jira rest api (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-dashboards/#api-rest-api-3-dashboard-dashboardid-gadget-post). However, there isn't any parameters to set 'Saved filter', 'Number of results' or 'Columns to display' for Filter Results gadget in the api. The only thing I can do with the api is create an empty gadget.
How can I configure gadgets using api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jira api, [set dashboard item properties](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-dashboards/#api-rest-api-3-dashboard-dashboardid-items-itemid-properties-propertykey-put), to configure gadgets (dashboard item).

```
payload = json.dumps({
    "filterId": "10711",
    "num": "50",
    "columnNames": "issuetype|summary|issuekey",
    "refresh": "true",
    "isConfigured": "true"
})

res = requests.request(
    "PUT",
    f"{HOST}/rest/api/3/dashboard/{dashboard_id}/items/{item_id}/properties/config",
    headers={
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data=payload,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(EMAIL, TOKEN)
)
```

Thanks for the answer from [Atlassian Community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-Server-questions/Jira-REST-API-for-configuring-dashboard-gadget/qaq-p/2080687).

Answer (score 1):

ScriptRunner has some support for this
https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/recipes/dashboard-gadgets.html

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It can solve my problem, but not suitable to my case 
 because ScriptRunner is too powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Not an official one, but 100% work.

End point: `/rest/dashboards/1.0/{dashboardId}/gadget/{gadgetId}/prefs`

Method: `PUT`

Example payload:

```
{
  "up_isConfigured": true,
  "up_num": "20",
  "up_refresh": "false",
  "up_columnNames": "issuetype|issuekey|summary|priority|assignee",
  "up_filterId": "10001"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the doc url for this api?

Comment: @Chiamin I already said "Not an official one", which means: that is an internal API, not the public API that you can see the docs, but I'm sure with you it will work 100%.

Comment: I'm curious how you get this api. Will it be removed or modified in the future? Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I can't tell you why here ;) But it won't be removed.